# Get latest record per timestamp in a left join query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I currently have 4 tables that I query to list status of orders.
Tables with relevant field look like this

```
+--------------+ +------------+ +----------+ +----------+
|Orders        | | Customers  | | Users    | | Status   |
+--------------+ +------------+ +----------+ +----------+
| id           | | id         | | id       | | id       |
| customer_id  | | name       | | name     | | order_id | 
| rep_id       | +------------+ +----------+ | status   |
+--------------+                             | comments |
                                             | date     |Timestamp
                                             | tech_id  |
                                             +----------+
```

Using the following SQL I can display the list of orders and status.

```
SELECT
      Orders.id AS orderid,
      Customers.name AS CLIENT,
      Users.name AS rep,
      Status.status
    FROM
      Orders
    LEFT JOIN
      Customers ON Orders.customer_id = Customers.id
    LEFT JOIN
      Users ON Orders.rep_id = Users.id
    LEFT JOIN
      Status ON Orders.id = Status.order_id
```

I get something like this.

```
+---------+----------+-------+--------+
| orderid | CLIENT   | rep   | status |
+---------+----------+-------+--------+
|       1 | Client 1 | Rep 1 | 1      |
|       2 | Client 2 | Rep 2 | 1      |
|       3 | Client 3 | Rep 1 | 1      |
|       4 | Client 4 | Rep 2 | 1      |
|       6 | Client 6 | Rep 4 | 1      |
|       1 | Client 1 | Rep 3 | 4      |
|       6 | Client 6 | Rep 4 | 4      |
+---------+----------+-------+--------+
```

I need to get one record per orderid based on the most recent date on the Status table. I feel that I'm so close however can't figure it out.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: This question has been answered many times. See the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT o.id AS orderid, c.name AS CLIENT, u.name AS rep,
       (SELECT s.status
        FROM status s
        WHERE o.id = s.order_id
        ORDER BY s.date DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) latest_status
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
     Customers c
     ON o.customer_id = c.id LEFT JOIN
     Users u
     ON o.rep_id = u.id ;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it working, just had to change status to Status a couple times.